# Mostrar imagen que se adapte a una card horizontal de Bootstrap4 y hacerlo responsive

Tags: bootstrap-4, card

Tengo un listado de card en Boostrap 4, pero depende del tamaño de la imagen se descuadra.

[image: Texto]

Quiero conseguir que da igual la foto que sea, se ajuste al cuadrado que tengo y todas las card tengan la misma proporción t tamaño, ya que pretendo hacer un listado con 8 iguales pero diferentes datos e imágenes pero no sé como ajustar la imagen.

Tambien, me gustaría poder hacerlo responsive, que a pantallas más pequeñas, se coloque la imagen arriba y el texto abajo, pero como no logro cuadrar la imagen, se me queda así:

[image: Texto]

Os dejo mi código por si me podéis explicar como lograrlo:

```
<div class="container my-4 w-100 cardEvents" >

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12 mt-3">

            <div class="card card-eventUpcoming">
                <div class="card-horizontal">
                    <div class="img-square-wrapper">
                        <img class="imageEvent" src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2020/11/02/13/15/reindeer-5706627_960_720.png" alt="Card image cap">
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-body card-body-events">
                        <p class="card-text date">DATE: 10-11-2020</p>
                    <h5 class="card-title title-event">EVENT NAME</h5>
                    <p class="card-text text-event">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed eiusmod tempor incidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua</p>
                    <p class="card-text consortium">Nombre</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
     
  <div class="card card-eventUpcoming">
                <div class="card-horizontal">
                    <div class="img-square-wrapper">
                        <img class="imageEvent" src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2019/10/06/18/27/meadow-hogweed-4530921_960_720.jpg" alt="Card image cap">
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-body card-body-events">
                        <p class="card-text date">DATE: 10-11-2020</p>
                    <h5 class="card-title title-event">EVENT NAME</h5>
                    <p class="card-text text-event">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed eiusmod tempor incidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua</p>
                    <p class="card-text consortium">Nombre</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Y el css:

```
.card-horizontal {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
}

.imageEvent{
  width:200px;
}
```